# AWS AppFlow data load from Salesforce to S3 Error initializing schema : Illegal character in: SystemModstamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, salesforce, amazon-appflow

I have created a flow in AWS AppFlow to pull data from Salesforce to AWS S3. The Object OppertunityHistory failed with the error - "Error initializing schema : Illegal character in: SystemModstamp". On querying Salesforce, the SystemModstamp field is in format 2021-02-13T03:38:37.000+0000. Any pointers on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few required fields were initially mapped. After mapping all the fields from Salesforce source object, the flow ran successfully.